# LibreSSL 2.0.5 - Why wasn't it fully affected by secadv_20140806.txt?

Tags: openssl

From: https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-announce&m=140752800525709

The announcement:

```
We have released LibreSSL 2.0.5, which should be arriving in the
LibreSSL directory of an OpenBSD mirror near you.

This version forward-ports security fixes from OpenSSL 1.0.1i,
including fixes for the following CVEs:

CVE-2014-3506
CVE-2014-3507
CVE-2014-3508 (partially vulnerable)
CVE-2014-3509
CVE-2014-3510
CVE-2014-3511

LibreSSL 2.0.4 was not found vulnerable to the following CVEs:

CVE-2014-5139
CVE-2014-3512
CVE-2014-3505

We welcome feedback and support from the community as we
continue to work on LibreSSL.

Thank you,
 Brent
```

**Our question is:** Why wasn't LibreSSL affected by the CVE-2014-5139, CVE-2014-3512, CVE-2014-3505 and only partially vulnerable for: CVE-2014-3508? Can someone please explain in short?

The OpenSSL Security Advisory Link: https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv_20140806.txt

Answer (score 4):

- [CVE-2014-5139](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1127491) - crash with SRP ciphersuite in Server Hello message - SRP had been [removed](https://github.com/libressl/libressl/commit/f089354ca79035afce9ec649f54c18711a950ecd) from LibreSSL in May 2014 so no fix was necessary.
- [CVE-2014-3512](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1127505) - SRP buffer overrun - again not vulnerable because SRP is no longer part of LibreSSL
- [CVE-2014-3505](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1127499) - Double Free when processing DTLS packets - this had been [fixed](https://github.com/libressl/libressl/commit/8591d448efd6c0c8d1837c2801e507ede919a281) independently by LibreSSL back in May 2014.
- [CVE-2014-3508](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1127490) - openssl: information leak in pretty printing functions - LibreSSL did indeed provide a [fix](https://github.com/libressl-portable/openbsd/commit/953bd49926cb710a5c36368fb5cbf7293837988b) for it. I have no information why the LibreSSL 2.0.5 release announcement marked it "partially vulnerable", someone with knowledge on that topic could compare the LibreSSL fix to the [OpenSSL fix](https://git.openssl.org/gitweb/?p=openssl.git;a=commit;h=0042fb5fd1c9d257d713b15a1f45da05cf5c1c87) to find out about that. **Update:** While searching for a more detailled explanation on that, I came across [this thread](http://undeadly.org/cgi?action=article&sid=20140808195101&pid=8&mode=expanded), where someone pretty much asked the same questions and one of the OpenBSD developers explained for CVE-2014-3508:

  > For -3508, one of the involved paths had been converted to snprintf()
  >   and could no longer leave the buffer unterminated, but we hadn't
  >   changed the other. Darn.

Note: I linked the CVEs to Redhat's Bugzilla, because they always link to the actual commitdiff fixing the issue, which is nice.